# Automatic flagging of "keto" users with Reputation == 1?

Tags: feature-request, spam-handling

I have not ever seen a question containing the word "keto" that was about Ubuntu. Is it possible to prevent Reputation 1 posters from posting a question containing "keto"?

Comment: This would be 'keyword blacklisting' which might be false-positive and I think is highly frowned upon by SE Staff..  It might be more useful to just *flag as spam*.

Comment: Related: [Can't edit due to mention of The Walking Dead](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7223/cant-edit-due-to-mention-of-the-walking-dead)

Answer (score 14):

I'm a room owner of [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) and a regular in [Charcoal-HQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq) and those rooms are involved in fighting spam posts across the SE network.

Thank you for noticing these spam posts and offering ideas to put a stop to them.

That specific spam is rather well known and persistent. Only on Ask Ubuntu over 2000 posts have been noticed and flagged. Even today 7 of such posts have been detected, which were deleted after 10, 20, 20, 120, 20, 5 and 60 seconds.

Other spam posts seen today on Ask Ubuntu were for the usual enhancements of body parts and for some investment program. Most of those were removed within minutes.

Do know that some spam posts for Ask Ubuntu are also reported in [Raiders of the Lost Downboat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3877/raiders-of-the-lost-downboat).

I admit that none of the above helps in actually preventing the post from even reaching the server and this might be a good moment to reassess if some of the detection logic can be moved to the SE servers. Do know that until that is done the community around Charcoal tries to clean up as soon as spam arrives. It is open for anyone to join.

Related reading:

- [A machine can flag spam automatically. Can it do better?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307585/a-machine-can-flag-spam-automatically-can-it-do-better)
- https://charcoal-se.org

Comment: I think you forgot to mention Baba ji :P

Comment: @Kulfy I didn't want my answer to be detected by Smokey ....

Comment: In addition to what rene has noted, Autoflagging has been nailing most Keto spam around SE (in most cases it gets 4 autoflags, and we tend to notice it more when it doesn't get 4). As such, the lifetime of posts like that are measured in minutes, if not seconds (depends how long it takes Charcoal's systems to notice)

Comment: As a mod, I have the dubious pleasure of seeing more spam than most. I remember how it was before smokey and the Charcoal Posse were around, and the Keto spam used to be a huge issue. It simply isn't one anymore thanks to the efforts of the great folks at Charcoal HQ.